# youtube_dl video descriptions

Tags: pandas, youtube-dl

I have a df containing a set of videoIDs from YT:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Order':  ['1', '2', '3'],
        'VideoID': ['jxwHmAoKte4', 'LsXM502SpiU','1I3f27iQ4pM']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Order','VideoID'])

print (df)
```

and want to download the video descriptions and save them in the same df in an extra column.

I tried to use youtube_dl in Jupyter this way:

```
import youtube_dl

def all_descriptions(URL):
    videoID=df['VideoId']
    URL = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + videoID
    ydl_opts = {
    'forcedescription':True,
    'skip_download': True,
    'youtube-skip-dash-manifest': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'ignoreerrors': True
    }
   
    try:
        youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts).download(URL)
        return webpage

except:
    pass

df['descriptions']=all_descriptions(URL)
```

I see the output of the code as text, but in df only "None" as text of the column.

Obviously I can't transport the output of the function to df in the proper way.

Can you suggest how to get it right?

Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@perl
I modify the df to include two URLs that are causing two types of error:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Order':  ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
        'VideoId': ['jxwHmAoKte4', 'LsXM502SpiU','1I3f27iQ4pM', 'MGQOX2rK5s', 'wNayw_E7lIA']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Order','VideoId'])

print (df)
```

Then I test it in the way you suggested, including my definition of ydl_opts:

```
videoID=df['VideoId']
URL = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + videoID
ydl_opts = {
    'forcedescription':True,
    'skip_download': True,
    'youtube-skip-dash-manifest': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'ignoreerrors': True
    }
    
df['description'] = [
    youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts).extract_info(
        u, download=False)['description'] for u in URL]

df
```

Reaching to the first error I get the output:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

After that I replace 'forcedescription' in my code with 'extract_info':

```
def all_descriptions(URL):
    videoID=df['VideoId']
    URL = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + videoID
    ydl_opts = {
    'forcedescription':True,
    'skip_download': True,
    'youtube-skip-dash-manifest': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'ignoreerrors': True
    }
   
    try:
        youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts).download(URL)
        return webpage
    
    except:
        pass
```

It skips all errors, but as the result there is nothing in the 'description'-column.

Any sugggestions?

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer with a version that will work with videos for which getting info fails

Comment: By the way, just for info for the next time, if you want to post some extra code, it is better to do so by updating your original question, not by posting it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `extract_info` method:

```
df['description'] = [
    youtube_dl.YoutubeDL().extract_info(
        u, download=False)['description'] for u in URL]

df
```

Output:

```
  Order      VideoID                                        description
0     1  jxwHmAoKte4  Bundesweit gelten sie nun ab heute, die schärf...
1     2  LsXM502SpiU  Wie sicher ist der Impfstoff? Wäre eine Impfpf...
2     3  1I3f27iQ4pM  Impfen ja oder nein, diese Frage stellen sich ...
```

P.S. The `forcedescription` parameter only prints the description to standard output, it doesn't return it

**Update:** `extract_info` returns `None` if it fails, so in case we have videos that may fail before getting the description from the info we can check that the info is not `None`:

```
ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts)
infos = [ydl.extract_info(u, download=False) for u in URL]
df['description'] = [
    info['description'] if info is not None else ''
    for info in infos]
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I add the code to skip errors? I had it as  'no_warnings': True,
 'ignoreerrors': True' above.

Comment: I haven't tested, but it should probably work with passing your options to YoutubeDL as `youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts).extract_info(...)`

Comment: I tried to modify it in two ways, but it didn't work: I will put my code in the answer below, so it would be more readable.

Comment: OK, yes, `extract_info` will return `None` if it fails, and we can't get description from `None`. Please see the update in my answer